# Car Turn Detection Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, rotation, geometry, automotive

I have timed sensor data for a car - such as Yaw Rate, Absolute Steering Angle etc - and would like to detect if the car is making a turn, left or right.

Currently, I'm thinking about using angular displacement and velocity, but I'm not sure if there's an existing robust algorithm that I could use.

I have also come across this post that hints about a method that could be used, but I'm not sure if this is exactly the one I need.

[Algorithm to detect left or right turn from x,y co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635188/algorithm-to-detect-left-or-right-turn-from-x-y-co-ordinates)

Sorry, for not giving much, but I'm actually trying to get some literature that I could review and some vocabulary that could help me find better solutions related to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Is your meaning of 'turn' distinct from following the curve of the road?

Comment: For now, no. I can later think about restricting the program specifically for turns or curves. But, for now, I think I'd love to get as many ideas as possible and read as much as I can.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "making a turn"?  It seems vague.  Probably you need to consider how you intend to use this decision to optimize the way you make it.

Comment: I see how it can be confusing. I'm actually looking to decide if the car made a turn, whether it made a right or left turn and the average speed with which the turn was made. I'm also doing some other calculations that require for me to know that at some specific instant in time, the car was going straight or turning at a specific angle.

Comment: This is probably a good place to start: https://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/

Comment: Isn't it simply a matter of tracking when the yaw rate is non-zero?

Comment: @Nico please can you explain some more to how non-zero Yaw rate alone can provide information that the vehicle has taken a 60 degrees turn? I thought it only gave angle at a certain point in time.

Comment: You didn't mention that you are looking for a specific angle in your question. Are you looking for circular arcs? What exactly do you mean by yaw rate and absolute steering angle? What is etc.?

Comment: If with a specific angle, you mean arbitrary angle, e.g. 60 degrees or 70 degrees etc., then yes. and yes, circular arcs would be great, but I'm exploring different techniques. I have vehicle sensor data at millisecond granularity for yaw rate, steering angle, Lateral sensor value, and wheel speed(in RPM).